# sql server 2008: combining two complex queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is one query that returns only 1 column called datapath:

```
SELECT  --assumes number not at end of string
    LEFT(startOf, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', startof)-1)
FROM
    (
    SELECT  --assumed 3 digits minimum
        SUBSTRING(datapath, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', datapath), 8000) AS startOf
    FROM
       (select datapath from batchinfo where LEN(datapath)>3) as bar
    ) foo
```

another words in this select statement below, instead of select datapath, i would like to run the above sql statement

```
SELECT reporttime,
                    datapath,
                    finalconc, 
                    instrument 
                    FROM batchinfo  
                    JOIN qvalues ON batchinfo.rowid = qvalues.rowid
                    WHERE compound = 3 AND name = "hey"
                   AND batchinfo.instrument = 44 
                   AND batchinfo.reporttime LIKE '10/%/2010%'";
```

Comment: What's the link between your datapath query and the fields in batchinfo?  **You need a way to say which rows match up.**

Comment: @jnk very good point, the logic is that instead of selecting datapath i want to select a subset of datapath, the subset of datapath is the first select statemenet

Comment: @i am girl - What I mean is, how do you know which datapath (from the subset) matches up to which row in batchinfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, I would think you should be able assign your 'datapath' column in the second select to the value you're selecting in the first, and replace 'startOf' with the value you're selecting for startOf.

I think it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  reporttime, 
  'datapath' = LEFT(SUBSTRING(datapath, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', datapath), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(datapath, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', datapath), 8000))-1) , 
  finalconc,  
  instrument  
FROM batchinfo   
JOIN qvalues ON batchinfo.rowid = qvalues.rowid 
WHERE compound = 3 AND name = "hey" 
AND batchinfo.instrument = 44  
AND batchinfo.reporttime LIKE '10/%/2010%'";
```

Comment: Impressive reformatting of my answer. And OP's [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108268/sql-server-2008-select-substring-from-a-field) Now add CASE for "number not found" and "number at end of line".

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT reporttime,
                    datapath,
                    finalconc, 
                    instrument 
      FROM

(
SELECT  --assumes number not at end of string
    LEFT(startOf, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', startof)-1) AS datapath, --correct?
    rowid, instrument , reporttime 
FROM
    (
    SELECT  --assumed 3 digits minimum
        SUBSTRING(datapath, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', datapath), 8000) AS startOf,
        rowid, instrument , reporttime
    FROM
       batchinfo --don't need LEN check. PATINDEX will do that implicitly
    ) foo

) batchinfo  
                    JOIN qvalues ON batchinfo.rowid = qvalues.rowid
                    WHERE compound = 3 AND name = "hey"
                   AND batchinfo.instrument = 44 
                   AND batchinfo.reporttime LIKE '10/%/2010%'";
```

Comment: @gbn btw i dont think your patindex works since it gave me errors, since some cells are length = 0

Comment: @jnk gbn says this is not the right approach because you are causing it to calculate it every time

Comment: @gbn what do u think of steven's answer?